# Amazon IAP testing does not show my icon

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, amazon-appstore

I'm using the SDK tester.json method to test my IAP stuff.  I've entered urls for my icons in the JSON, but the IAP confirmation dialog just shows a default icon that says "Test Item".  Is this just the way the test environment works (i.e. it never shows my icons until I test it live), or have I set it up incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon's tech support people verified this is the way it is supposed to happen in tester.